# Execute Shell Command Synchronously with Elixir/Erlang

Tags: elixir

I want to execute a (slow) python script and I want my Elixir process to block until it's receives all the output from the script.

Are either Elixir's System.cmd/3 or Erlang's os:cmd/1 guaranteed to be synchronous? If not, is there some other way to make a synchronous os call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[os:cmd](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#cmd-1)

> Executes Command in a command shell of the target OS, captures the
>   standard output of the command and returns this result as a string.
>   This function is a replacement of the previous unix:cmd/1; on a Unix
>   platform they are equivalent.

This command is synchronous .

Comment: Wasn't sure. Thanks.